# unable to assign hiddenfield value to select2 on postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-select2

I am trying to assign value to select2 control from a hiddenfield in clientside script. Value is not assigned to select2 control after postback for the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#cboIndustry").select2();

     $.getJSON(uriSector+ '/' + 'GetIndustrySectors')
           .done(function (data) {
               $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                  $("#cboIndustry").append($("<option></option>").val(item.IndustrySectorID).html(item.IndustrySectorName));
               });
           });

     $("#cboIndustry").on('change', function () {
            if ($("#cboIndustry").val() != "-1") {

                 var id = $("#cboIndustry").val();
                $('#HiddenIndustrySectorID').val(id);
                SelectedName = $('#cboIndustry option:selected').text();
                $('#HiddenIndustrySectorName').val(SelectedName);
            }
        });

   var SelectedIndustry = $('#HiddenIndustrySectorID').val();

   $("#cboIndustry").select2().select('val',SelectedIndustry);

});
```

**However value get assigned if I put alert before assigning**

```
var SelectedIndustry = $('#HiddenIndustrySectorID').val(); 

alert(SelectedIndustry);

$("#cboIndustry").select2().select('val',SelectedIndustry); 

// These steps I have included, for retaining value in select2 on postback.
```

What could be the reason? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cboIndustry").select2();

    $.getJSON(uriSector+ '/' + 'GetIndustrySectors')
       .done(function (data) {
           $.each(data, function (key, item) {
              $("#cboIndustry").append($("<option></option>").val(item.IndustrySectorID).html(item.IndustrySectorName));
        });
    //This change solves my problem

    var SelectedIndustry = $('#HiddenIndustrySectorID').val();

    $("#cboIndustry").select2().select('val',SelectedIndustry);

 });

 $("#cboIndustry").on('change', function () {
        if ($("#cboIndustry").val() != "-1") {
            var id = $("#cboIndustry").val();
            $('#HiddenIndustrySectorID').val(id);
            SelectedName = $('#cboIndustry option:selected').text();
            $('#HiddenIndustrySectorName').val(SelectedName);
        }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use this line

```
$("#cboIndustry").select2().val(SelectedIndustry);
```

BTW i have not tested

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#HiddenIndustrySectorID').val(id);
```

Change this line to

```
document.getElementById("HiddenIndustrySectorID").value =id;
```

and try